# Почему flex: 1 1 auto не работает с flex-direction: column?

Tags: css, flexbox

[image]

Как только я меняю с row на column flex не применяется

Comment: Код добавляйте НЕ картинкой, а текстом.

Comment: Код текстом. Для CSS нужен ещё HTML к которому он применяется.

Comment: у вас написано что wrapper имеет минимальную высоту в 100% а это 0

Comment: Вопрос на самом деле актуален - у меня такая же проблема. С заменой на vh работает, но куда удобнее было бы делать 100%, поскольку в некоторых местах нужно сделать флекс-колонку внутри другой флекс-колонки. И, к примеру, одной задать 100% высоты от родительской. Не работает даже это. Бьюсь второй день, ничего не выходит.

Comment: руки бы оторвать, кто данному вопросу плюсы ставит.....

Comment: у меня подобная проблема.. ни один, из предложенных здесь вариантов, мне не помог.. может есть еще?

Answer (score -1):

```
html, body
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

пропиши и всё заработает.

Answer (score -1):

Вот простое решение:

```
.wrapper {
  min-height:100%; - поменяйте значение % на vh.
}
```

мне помогло.

Comment: А что такое - _footer лёг как миленький_?